# How to pass dynamically JSON test data file to json spec.js file to get data in Cypress + Cucumber?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, cucumber, bdd, cypress

I want to run same test for the same web page for different combinations. Therefore I'm planning to created different scenarios in same feature file or different files. I have already tried passing login details as parameters from feature file but when I try pass JSON file name read data inside of the file, this process fails to do so.

> Note : I don't want to loop through different set of data files. Instead pass each file name through feature file

Below is the code
[image: DealTest.feature]
purchase is the file name

DealTest.spec.js
[image: DealTest.spec.js]

This is DealPage.spec.js
[image: DealPage.spec.js]

I have added the code below

Feature file

```
When User Navigate into Record deal screen "purchaseBill"
When User select dealer
```

DealTest.spec.js

```
var testData;
When ('User Navigate into Record deal screen {string}', (jsonFileName) => {
    cy.fixture(jsonFileName).then(function(jsonData){
        testData = jsonData
    })   
    cy.log('Dealer name should be in the log as this ----> '+ testData.dealerCode)
    recordDealPage.validateDealMenu()

})     


When ('User select dealer', (testData) => {
   recordDealPage.selectDealer(testData.dealerCode)
   cy.log('Dealer name should be in the log as this inside (inside method) ----> '+ 
   testData.dealerCode)
})
```

DealPage.spec.js

```
class RecordDealPage{      
    selectDealer(testData){  
       cy.log('Dealer name should be in the log as this ----> '+ test.dealerCode)
       cy.get('#dealerCode').type(testData.dealerCode)
       cy.wait(2000)
       cy.get('#dealerCode').type('{downarrow}').type('{enter}')
       
 
   }   
}
```

JSON datafile purchase.json

```
{
     "dealerCode": "testDealer",
     "customerCode": "Customer1"
}
```

This is what I get when run the test
[image: Test error image]

**I'm using Cypress and Cucumber**